# Visual Studio 2022 Community: Tab Spacing Off (Extra Indent?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, indentation, auto-indent

Just a few days ago Visual Studio (VS) 2022 Community seemed to be indenting fine for me, placing the cursor indented after a line of braces with braces lining up and so on. Today, however, I found that it was indenting a line after pressing "Enter." I thought I had fixed this after setting no tabs to be inserted after newlines (for IntelliSense), but indentation generally still seems to be off.

Example #1:
With `Indenting` set to `Smart`, if I set `tab size` as `4` and `indent size` as `4`, then when trying to type the opening brace for class `Foo`, I get the following result:

```
public class Foo
    {
        int bar;
    }
```

Now the four spaces (relatively speaking) between the curly braces and the `int` of `int bar;` are desired, but what is with the leading indentation of the braces?

Example #2:
If I now set `Indenting` to `Block`, (and still with `tab size` and `indent size` as both `4`), then I get this for the same attempted code as for the above example:

```
public class Foo 
{
        int bar;
}
```

Now there are eight spaces leading the `int` of `int bar;`. Likewise, what is up with the indentation here?

I can of course turn off `Smart` or `Block` indentation, but then I'm back to manual, which, by the way, gives me the following for the same tab size and indent size as above (`4`) when I go to type out the `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{

    }
```

And if I then go to write the `int bar;`, an extra indentation occurs, giving:

```
public class Foo
{
        int bar;
    }
```

So no matter how I seem to set the Indentation-specific setting for the language (C#), I end up with a weird case of indentation involving an extra indent somewhere (Example #1 had it before the two braces; Example #2 had it before the `int bar;`; and manually has it before the closing brace and again with `int bar;`.) May I ask how to resolve this indentation, to return to how it was before (where indentation was automatically recognized to be four spaces for a block, without unneeded extra indentation being inserted while also not having it be manual)?

Also, just in case, the `tab size` and `indent size` for "All Languages" as well as for C# are set to `4`. The above setting of `Indenting` (`Smart`, then `Block`, then `None` for the above three examples, respectively) is for C# specifically; when I try to set it for "All Languages", I get the message:

> The indentation settings for individual text formats conflict with each other.

and so the radio buttons for `Indenting` for "All Languages" remains unselected even if I do select one.

Comment: Do the extra indents exist in a new file?

Comment: @shingo sorry, how do you mean? As in if I create a new C# file and do the same there?

Comment: Yes, if you type in the new file, will there also be these extra spaces?

Comment: Have you tried  the reset option?